# angular bootstrap modal show does not get triggered

Tags: css, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to implement a simple Modal from Angular Bootstrap (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal)

However when I click the button in the example (locally implemented) the `ngb-modal-window` element does not transition to opacity 1. But as you can see it does contain the right classes (fade show):

**Code:**

```
<ngb-modal-window role="dialog" style="display: block;" tabindex="-1" ng-reflect-class-name="modal fade show" class="modal fade show">
```

This results in missing css on the same element:

```
.fade.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This part is missing in my implementation for unknown reason while it is showing in the plunker/demosites.

I tried to manually add this to my components css in two ways:

```
.fade.show {
    opacity: 1;
}

ngb-modal-window.modal.fade.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Both did not work.

What could be the reason? Am I missing something trivial?

Further information:

- `<template ngbModalContainer></template>` was included
- NgbModal is imported in the component
- bootstrap version 4.0.0-alpha.5

Comment: I don't see any transition in your CSS

Comment: normally the animations should be part of bootstrap itself. the mentioned transition should be part of https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/scss/_transitions.scss. Somehow this does not get loaded/added to the element. So I normally would have an empty css file and not manually enter transitions. If that is what you are asking about

Comment: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1293 this was an bootstrap css update issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1293

This is fixed in bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6